# pyusb: Send command to OS

Tags: python, operating-system, usb

Using [pyusb](https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst) it is possible to capture packets from devices like USB keyboards. Is it possible to use those captured raw packets to send keystrokes to application or OS?